# Chris Pine Ch. 6 Deaf Grandma

Tags: ruby

I am following [Chris Pine](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_06.html) tutorial. In one of the exercises I have to write to "Grandma" BYE three times in a row to shut the program. But my program can shut even if I don't type "bye" three times in a row. Why?

```
    puts "Do you need anything?".upcase
answer = " "
number = 1900
bye_count = 0

while true
    answer = gets.chomp
    if answer == answer.downcase
        puts "Speak up!".upcase
    elsif answer == "BYE"
        bye_count = bye_count + 1
        if bye_count == 3
            puts "Okay then!".upcase
            break
        end
    else
        puts "No, not since #{number + rand(35)}".upcase
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's okay, my grandma is the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the program to only stop when it receives the input `'BYE'` three times in a row, then you need to reset the `bye_count` to 0 whenever the input isn't `'BYE'`.

```
puts "Do you need anything?".upcase
answer = " "
number = 1900
bye_count = 0

while true
  answer = gets.chomp
  if answer == answer.downcase
    bye_count = 0
    puts "Speak up!".upcase
  elsif answer == "BYE"
    bye_count = bye_count + 1
    if bye_count == 3
      puts "Okay then!".upcase
      break
    end
  else
    bye_count = 0
    puts "No, not since #{number + rand(35)}".upcase
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset `bye_count` to 0 if you say something other than `BYE`.